# Convert series of categorized data into a dataframe with a multi-index containing category and a new id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Supposing I have a dataframe like this:

```
In [6]: data = {
   ...:     'Name': ['A']*3 + ['B']*5 + ['C']*2,
   ...:     'Values': np.random.rand(10)
   ...: }
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   ...: df
   ...:
Out[6]:
  Name    Values
0    A  0.742881
1    A  0.392682
2    A  0.522659
3    B  0.700985
4    B  0.465056
5    B  0.005102
6    B  0.081476
7    B  0.234193
8    C  0.410230
9    C  0.728146
```

Is there an easier way to convert it to a multi-indexed dataframe/series like this where the second index is a new id that identifies each 'repeat' of data with the same name.

```
In [7]: tuples = tuple(zip(df.Name, list(range(3)) + list(range(5)) + list(range(2))))
   ...: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Name', 'Item ID'])
   ...: desired_df = pd.DataFrame(data=df.Values.tolist(), index=index)
   ...: desired_df
   ...:
Out[7]:
                     0
Name Item ID
A    0        0.742881
     1        0.392682
     2        0.522659
B    0        0.700985
     1        0.465056
     2        0.005102
     3        0.081476
     4        0.234193
C    0        0.410230
     1        0.728146
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Name', df.groupby('Name')['Name'].cumcount().rename('Item ID')])
print (df)

                Values
Name Item ID          
A    0        0.543312
     1        0.647681
     2        0.050414
B    0        0.231535
     1        0.460839
     2        0.400258
     3        0.537909
     4        0.352586
C    0        0.533528
     1        0.662036
```